# Function to write to file via fstream in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I create a file wit a specified name:

```
#include <fstream>

SYSTEMTIME systime;
GetSystemTime (&systime);

CString filename;
filename =     specifyNameOfFile(timestamp, suffix); // call a method

std::ofstream fstream(filename,     std::ios_base::app | std::ips_base::out);
```

And I want to create a method like

```
void WriteToFile(unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result);

void WriteToFile(unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result) 
{
    fstream << count << " " << hour << " " << minute << " " << result << "\n";
}
```

Which will take input the content to be written to the file and should use the previously defined fstream.

I tried adding the fstream to the input of the function but didn't work:

```
void WriteToFile(std::ofstream fstream, unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result);
```

which gave `error C2248` at `VC\include\fstream(803) : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem, _Traits>'`.

Can someone suggest a solution to show what I don't understand how to do?

Comment: *How* did you try to "adding the fstream to the input of the function"? Can you please show us? And what problems did you have with it? And if you haven't done so yet, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Modified my question to tackle the shortcomings you mentioned. Thanks for pointing them out. Hope now these are sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the function is declared as

```
void WriteToFile(std::ofstream fstream, unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result);
```

There is a problem with this, because you try to pass the stream *by value*, which means it gets copied. And you can not copy a stream object.

Pass it *by reference* instead:

```
void WriteToFile(std::ofstream& fstream, unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result);
//                            ^
//                            Note ampersand here
```

---

On an unrelated note, to make it more compatible with other streams I suggest you use the base class `std::ostream` instead:

```
void WriteToFile(std::ostream& ostream, unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result);
```

Now you can pass *any* kind of output stream (files, string, `std::cout`) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment (reputation...), and to be fair, I don't quite understand what you want, and what is your problem, so just a few comments on the code you've shared (hope this helps a little as well):

1)

```
CString filename;
filename = ...
Would be much prettier like this:
CString filename = ...
```

(compiler will take care of this anyway, but still)

2) There's a typo here:
specifyNaneOfFile
I guess this should be 
specifyNameOfFile

3) In the signature of your function:

```
void WriteToFile(unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char result);
```

'result' is not taken by reference. I guess you want this to give the caller some information if writing was successful (why not bool WriteToFile?). This way, no matter what you set 'result' in your function, it will only affect your function, the caller will get what it gave.
ie.:
Let's assume this is your function:

```
void MyClass::WriteToFile(unsigned char result)
{
result = 1;
}
```

The caller calls it like this:

```
unsigned char writeResult = 0;
WriteToFile(writeResult)

if (writeResult == 1) ...
```

writeResult will remain 0.

If you want it to change, pass as reference, like this:

```
void WriteToFile(unsigned int count, WORD hour, WORD minute, unsigned char &result);
```

Also, use 'const' for every parameter you don't intend to change.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will take them into account. Please note that I updated my question and hopefully it will better for you to understand and suggest a solution to my issue.

Comment: Check @Some programmer dude's answer below mine. I would just say the same for the updated question. :)